# single-{post-type}.php

Tags: custom-post-types

I have implemented a custom post-type "project". To see the page of the archives of these custom post types, I created an archive-projet.php 
To see this page, I type http://localhost/my-website/?post_type=project
so far no problems .....
Where it gets complicated is when I want to see the single-projet.php page.

When I click on the link in the project archive-projet.php page, a blank page is displayed! I do not understand ! Someone would have any idea ? Thank you for your lights.

Comment: do you mean `single-project.php` or `single-projet.php`? What is the URL of the link? Are there messages in your PHP error log? It sounds like you've made a mistake in your `single-project.php` file, a syntax error and it's causing a PHP Fatal error, but your server is configured not to display errors so instead nothing is shown

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on the amount of times you missed the c from the word project... my first recommendation would be to check for typos in your code/file names :)

Try updating permalinks in here: /wp-admin/options-permalink.php. Just hit update, and see if that solves the problem.

Also, see if any errors are getting reported, open up wp-config and change `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` to `true`. Then try your single page again and see if any errors come back.

You could also check your PHP error logs for any signs.

Comment: Hi Tom, you rock, it works ! The problem was with the permalinks.I just updated and now permalinks Works!

Comment: Excellent stuff! I've been bitten many a time by that too!

Answer (score 0):

I can reiterate what Tom J Nowell said.... also install the WP [Debug Bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) plugin, specifically the WP_Query tab in this instance, which is super helpful at determining what template WordPress is using to render the current page:

i.e. [image: WP_Query tab of Debug Bar]

Comment: Great plugin setterGetter, Will put it in my plugin collection ! thank you for sharing